# How to get the members of the group in Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

With the help of event handler i am getting the id of the user who have finished the Workflow activity.

For getting the Id i am writing like:

`foreach(var user  in activity.Performers)`

`userId=user.Title.ToString();`

Now, similarly how can i get the members of the group(their id's) to which the user belongs.

Comment: it seems some part of code is missing in your post?

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the event handler then you are using TOM.NET. 
You need to get list of users in the group. Each group has `GetGroupMembers` method that you can use.
Here's the code you need:

```
foreach (var user in activity.Performers)
{
     var groupMemberships = ((User)user).GroupMemberships;

     var filter = new GroupMembersFilter(session);
     foreach (var groupMembership in groupMemberships)
     {
         var users = groupMembership.Group.GetGroupMembers(filter);
     }
}
```

You can control how much data you get back by setting properties of `filter`

Comment: I tried to log the users which is returning in "users" It is returning System.Collections.Generic.List. I had the namespace using System.Collections.Generic included. Please help.

Comment: @pavan Not sure what your problem exactly is, but I have updated my answer with your inputs