# How to get the users of the group when group id and group name is known

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Basing on the user who finishes the workflow activity i am getting the "groupid and groupname" to which the user belongs. Now basing on groupid how can i get the list of users of that group. Please suggest.

Comment: What did you already try? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: In eventhandler i am getting the id and title values:
`UserData user = (UserData)csClient.Read(performer.Id, readoption);
foreach (var GetGroupMember in user.GroupMemberships)
{
string grptitle = GetGroupMember.Group.Title;
string grpId = GetGroupMember.Group.IdRef;
}`

Comment: I saw your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243526/how-to-get-the-members-of-the-group-in-tridion) where User978511 provided you with an answer. But now what did you try with that code and what is your problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really  just a "Just in case FYI" - You have not stated what you are trying to do with the members of a group once you have retrieved them, but keep in mind that most members are members of groups with a certain scope rather than for all publications.

So be careful if you are trying to do something like getting all the editors for Publication A, you may run into problems if you are using just the Editors group, as it could contain members who do not have access to Publication A.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `GetGroupMembers`